# Advantage of virtual memory without swap?

Tags: swap, virtual-memory

Is there any advantage of virtual memory when we only use the existing RAM and no swap-space?

Comment: What do you mean by virtual memory?

Comment: Sure. Memory protection/security would be the big one, and even without writable swap you may still be able to page out constant code/data. Among other things.

Comment: You'd still want contiguous linear memory and file mapping, and you could do something like zram/compcache to have "swap without swap".

Comment: Virtual memory separates distinct processes preventing cross-corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refer to Virtual Memory, maybe you have in your mind a couple of things:

- Possibility of swapping
- Memory Protection (one process can't crash another, or crash the OS)
- Address-translation (virtual memory addresses to physical addresses)
- Something else I might not remember.

A given architecture doesn't necessarily have to support all of those, but like user3344003 pointed out, most mainstream systems support all of those.
In theory you can have for example just Memory Protection, and nothing else, like in my pet project https://bitbucket.org/ruifig/g4devkit

If you mean Virtual Memory in that broad sense, then one thing it's really useful for other than swap-space, is that it makes implementation of Shared Libraries (aka: DLLs in Windows) so much easier. You can be using just the existing RAM, but by having address-translation, it makes it easier to share code between processes.

There are tricks to support shared libraries in systems without Virtual memory/Address-translation, but it's quite messy when compared with the simplicity that Virtual Memory/Address-translation gives you.

Answer (score -1):

Virtual memory systems do not work unless there is paging space. Every page frame has to be mapped to disk somewhere. As such, there is no advantage to having VM and no page file space.

Comment: Well that was true in the 90's, when swapping was basically the motivation for (and almost the definition of) virtual memory. But that's obsolete.

Comment: That's not just the motivation; its the implementation as well. That's what virtual memory is. In the future, it is likely we will have logical memory translation without virtual memory. So far, there are no (at least mainstream) systems that operate in that manner.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're using the ancient definition of virtual memory there. It *used to be* about the swapping deal (so, it *was* by definition required to have swap in order to be virtual memory), but it hasn't been like that for a long time now. And FWIW, both Windows and Linux can operate without swap but require virtual memory for, well, everything.

Comment: If you don't have paging you don't have virtual memory. You could have logical memory translation.